# django custom validation - reference submitted form value

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to [django custom validate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/) a form field.

I have written the code below, but I cannot think of how to reference the submitted value of the **employment_record_date_display_type** that is included in the EmploymentRecordForm.

I tried *employment_record_date_display_type = EmploymentRecordForm.employment_record_date_display_type* but it gives the following error:

*type object 'EmploymentRecordForm' has no attribute 'employment_record_date_display_type'*

Here is the validation code in my forms.py file:

```
class EmploymentRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    .............
    def clean_employment_record_completion_date(self):

        employment_record_display_type = self.cleaned_data.get('employment_record_display_type')
        employment_record_date_display_type = ?????????
        employment_record_commencement_date = self.cleaned_data.get('employment_record_commencement_date')
        employment_record_completion_date = self.cleaned_data.get('employment_record_completion_date')

        if employment_record_display_type == 0:
            if employment_record_completion_date is not None and employment_record_commencement_date is not None:
                if employment_record_commencement_date > employment_record_completion_date:
                    if employment_record_date_display_type == 2 or employment_record_date_display_type == 3:
                        raise forms.ValidationError(_("To Date must be greater than the From Date."))
                    elif employment_record_date_display_type == 4 or employment_record_date_display_type == 5:
                        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Finish Date must be greater than the Start Date."))
                    elif employment_record_date_display_type == 6 or employment_record_date_display_type == 7:
                        raise forms.ValidationError(_("End Date must be greater than the Begin Date."))
                    elif employment_record_date_display_type == 8 or employment_record_date_display_type == 9:
                        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This Date must be greater than the other Date."))
                    else:
                        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Completion Date must be after the Commencement Date."))

        return employment_record_completion_date
```

**How do I reference the submitted value of the employment_record_date_display_type ?**

Comment: Try `self.data['employment_record_date_display_type']`

Comment: Ajeeb.K.P, thanks but that does not work.

Comment: What about `self.instance.employment_record_date_display_type`!

Comment: Ajeeb.K.P, thanks but that does not work either.

Comment: By the way, what is don't you take cleaned_data?

Comment: do you have any field in model/form named `employment_record_date_display_type`, if not, how are intending to get it if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Ajeeb.K.P, cleaned_data did not return a value.

Comment: rudda, there is a model/form element named employment_record_date_display_type, but I can still not return the value.

Comment: check if you have some how popped this field from `__init__` of modelform or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your custom validator class and in fields you want you should have validators list property. Something like this:

```
price = models.IntegerField(validators=[MyCustomValidator])
```